# Changing a bool to an enum in Entity Framework - code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have code-first generated database. In it I have a bool column in a table. This column needs to be changed to an enum. Problem is the table already has data, which has to be somehow converted.
What I have
bool IsA: true/false
what I need
enum MyEnum:
A,B,C,D
I need the values of IsA converted so that true maps to A and false maps to B. 
How can I do this?

Comment: It must work automatically. Just change property type from bool to `MyEnum` in your entity. Have you tried this?

Comment: No I haven't. How will it know which value is meant to be true and which is meant to be false? Also, I need the column to have a different name as well.

Comment: You must set enum member's values correspondingle like: `MyEnum { A = 1, B  = 0} `

Comment: as bit is included in integer in most DBMS and enums are mapped to integer columns, you can simply change the column type to integer (and update values already in the database if necessary)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to do this at migration class:

```
public partial class fromBool2Enum : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        //add new column:
        AddColumn("dbo.MyTable", "IsA_TEMP", c => c.Int());
        //transfer data to just created column
        Sql("Update dbo.MyTable set IsA_TEMP = case when IsA then 0 else 1 end");
        //0(i.e. A) and 1(i.e. B) is just example, correct it on your own, depending on enum's declaration

        //Drop old column
        DropColumn("dbo.MyTable", "IsA")
        //Rename new column to initial name
        Sql("EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.MyTable.IsA_TEMP', 'IsA', 'COLUMN'");            
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
         //corresponding reverse code...
    }       
}
```